# How can I scrape Informations from a Website, that are constantly updated?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get informations about not occupied parking space in a car park. The info on the website is constantly updating the numbers of free parking spots.

Since I'm on the beginning of learning webscraping with R, I started learning the basics. 
So I tried getting the Year of an IMDB Movie with the code

```
url2 <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature"
page2 <- read_html(url2)

data2 <- page2 %>%
  html_node(".lister-item-year") %>%
  html_text
data2
```

This code is running with no problems.

Now I tried the same with the website about parking spots and since the HTML Code is almost the same as in the example above, I figured it shouldn't be that hard.

```
url <- "https://www.rosenheim.de/stadt-buerger/verkehr/parken.html"

page <- read_html(url)

data <- page %>%
  html_node('.jwGetFreeParking-8') %>%
  html_text
data
```

But as a result I don't get the information about free parking spots. The Result I get is "". So nothing.

Is it because the number on the second webpage is updating from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

This page is rendered using javascript thus the techniques from your example don't apply. If you use the developer tools from your browser and examine the files loaded on the network tab, you will find a file named "index.php".  This is a JSON file containing the parking information.

Downloading this file will provide the requested information.  The `fromJSON` function the "jsonlite" library will access the file and convert it into a data frame.

```
library(jsonlite)

answer<-fromJSON("https://www.rosenheim.de/index.php?eID=jwParkingGetParkings")
answer

   uid                     title parkings occupied free isOpened link
1    4                   Reserve        0        0  ---    FALSE    0
2    7                   Reserve        0        0  ---    FALSE    0
3   13                   Reserve        0        0  ---    FALSE    0
4   14                   Reserve        0        0  ---    FALSE    0
5    0                P1 Zentrum      257      253    4     TRUE  224
6    1                  P2 KU'KO      138      133    5     TRUE  225
7    2                P3 Rathaus       31       29    2     TRUE  226
8    3                  P4 Mitte      275      275    0     TRUE  227
9    5             P6 Salinplatz      232      148   84     TRUE  228
10   6           P7 Altstadt-Ost       82      108    0     TRUE  229
11  10      P8 Beilhack-Citydome      160      130   30     TRUE  230
12   8            P9 Am Klinikum      426      424    2     TRUE 1053
13   9           P10 Stadtcenter       56       54    2     TRUE  231
14  11 P11 Beilhack-Gießereistr.      155      155  ---    FALSE 1151
15  12          P12 Bahnhof Nord      148       45  103     TRUE 1203
```